# In machine learning which algorithm should I use to recommend, based on different features like rating,type,gender etc

Tags: machine-learning, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, data-science

I am developing a website, which will recommend recipes to the visitors based on their data. I am collecting data from their profile, website activity and facebook.

Currently I have data like [username/userId, rating of recipes, age, gender, type(veg/Non veg), cuisine(Italian/Chinese.. etc.)]. With respect to above features I want to recommend new recipes which they have not visited.

I have implemented ALS (alternating least squares) spark algorithm. In this we have to prepare csv which contains [userId,RecipesId,Rating] columns. Then we have to train this data and create the model by adjusting parameters like lamdas, Rank, iteration. This model generated recommendation, using pyspark

> model.recommendProducts(userId, numberOfRecommendations)

The ALS algorithm accepts only three features userId, RecipesId, Rating. I am unable to include more features (like type, cuisine, gender etc.) apart from which I have mentioned above (userId, RecipesId, Rating). I want to include those features, then train the model and generate recommendations.

Is there any other algorithm in which I can include above parameters and generate recommendation.

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are couple of others algorithms. For your case, I would suggest that you Naive Bayes algorithm.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier

Since you are working on a web application, a JS solution, I guess, would come handy to you.

(simple) https://www.npmjs.com/package/bayes

or for example:

(a bit more powerful) https://www.npmjs.com/package/naivebayesclassifier

Comment: Thank you so much for your valuable response. I will go through it and get back to you if I stuck somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

There are algorithms called recommender systems in machine learning. In this we have content based recommender systems. They are mainly used to recommend products/movies based on customer reviews. You can apply the same algorithm using customer reviews to recommend recipes. For better understanding of this algorithm refer this links:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bv6VkpvEeRw&list=PL0Smm0jPm9WcCsYvbhPCdizqNKps69W4Z&index=97

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2uxXPzm-7FY

You can go with powerful classification algorithms like

->SVM: works very well if you have more number of attributes.

->Logistic Regression: if you have huge data of customers.

Comment: Thank you so much for your valuable response. I will go through these videos and get back to you if I stuck somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for recommender systems using algorithms like collaborative filtering. I would suggest you to go through Prof.Andrew Ng's short videos on collaborative filtering algorithm and low-rank matrix factorization and also building recommender systems. They are a part of Coursera's Machine learning course offered  by Stanford University. 
The course link:
https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning#%20

You can check week 9 for the content related to recommender systems.

Comment: Thank you so much for your valuable response. I will definitely go through this course.